# Failed to send model to a controller in asp mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So this is my edit controller:

```
namespace WebFront_End.Controllers
{
    public class EditController : Controller
    {
        private ActiviteitContainer AC = new(new ActiviteitenMSSQLDAL());
        public IActionResult Index(ActiviteitVM activiteit)
        {
            return View(activiteit);
        }

        public IActionResult Return(ActiviteitVM activiteit)
        {

            AC.UpdateActivityWithDayOnly(activiteit.ToActiviteit(), HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId").Value);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

this is the home page where the edit button should send the model to the edit view:

```
@model UserVM
@using WebFront_End.Models
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<h1>Hello @Model.GetFullName()</h1>

<div class="container border">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col AC_header">
            <p>Type</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col AC_header">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col AC_header">
            <p>Start Time</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col AC_header">
            <p>End Time</p>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    @foreach (ActiviteitVM a in Model.activiteiten)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col AC">
                <p>@a.Type</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col AC">
                <p>@a.Name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col AC">
                <p>@a.Date</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col AC">
                <p>@a.Date</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            </div>
            <form asp-controller="Edit" asp-action=Index asp-route-activiteit="@a" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </form>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

this is my Edit view which gets it model from the home view:

```
@model ActiviteitVM
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<form asp-controller="Edit" asp-action=Return method="post">
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <div>
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input asp-for=Name value= "@Model.Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Type">Type</label>
        <input asp-for=Type value="@Model.Type" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Description">Description</label>
        <input asp-for=Description value="@Model.Description" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Date">Date</label>
        <input asp-for=Date value ="@Model.Date.Date.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD")" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

The fields are empty so that means the model is empty, which is weird because there is a model needed to get to the page. Which means its sending a empty model. I can't see the problem maybe in the foreach loop?

Comment: Hi @Meadas, `The fields are empty so that means the model is empty` do you mean when you post the form to `Edit/Index`, it cannot render the edit view with model data? Actually complex model cannot be posted by `asp-route-` tag helper, I think you need pass unique key like id to `asp-route-id` and receive `id` in Index action. In this action, you can use linq to find the model data by id.

Comment: @Rena Yes that's what I did after all, did not know you couldn't send a model through asp-route-. Thanks still!